# delete all constraint repl_identity_range from database

Tags: sql-server, constraints, replication

I use this code and bing me constraint that create from replication.
How can I batch delete this constraint from my database ?
I want to delete constraint in each table that start with `repl_...` like this:

> repl_identity_range_B71717D4_E729_4EA9_A7DC_0953608A61FB

```
 select 
    object_name(constid) as "Constraint name",
    object_name(sysconstraints.id) as"Table name" ,
    [TEXT]
    from sysconstraints join syscomments on syscomments.id =sysconstraints.constid
     where object_name(constid) like  '%repl%' 
    order by [Table name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the result set, for each constraint definition construct an appropriate ALTER TABLE statement and execute that.

Perhaps you can best do this in an SQL procedure.

Comment: No, don't know SQL/PSM language in enough detail to do that and at any rate, SQL procedure language can be very different from one DBMS to another.  Most DBMS's already had some form of procedure language before it got standardized and hardly any ever aligned to the standard post factum.  You'd have to label the question with the specific DBMS you're using.  Only point of my answer was to make it clear that if you were hoping for some magical single SQL statement, you can (most probably) end hoping.

Comment: i use sql server 2014

Comment: I found out the solution and this worked for me :
this code  delete constraint replication orphaned from all table: but StackOverflow does not allow me to put my answer or put the long code here . how can i put answer here ?

Comment: post it as an answer